# Adding to a powershell array with only two elements does not work

Tags: powershell

Say I have the following code:

```
$roles = @("first", "second", "third")

$roles = $roles | Where-Object {$_ -ne "second"}       
$roles += "last"

$roles
```

This will result in the following output:

> first
> third
> last

Just what I would expect.  But if I take out the `"thrid"` element of the array, then it performs oddly.  Here is the code I run (in VS Code):

```
$roles = @("first", "second")

$roles = $roles | Where-Object {$_ -ne "second"}       
$roles += "last"

$roles
```

This results in the following:

> firstlast

(all on one line)

Is Powershell changing my variable to be a string when I pull out the second to last array?  If so, how do I stop it from doing that?  If not, what is going on here?

**Why is my array all of a sudden working like a string?**

Comment: You can wrap all the expression in [`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) to force an array

Comment: `($roles | Where-Object {$_ -ne "second"}).GetType()` will reveal what's going on.  Why would you expect a scalar element of an array to, itself, be an array?  That you are operating on an array does not mean all of those operations produce arrays, too.  If you want them to, though, you can make it so with the `@()` operator you're already using, as that's what it's for.